# Is 1 always an element in multiplicative group?

Tags: group-theory

Let  $\mathbb{G}_T$ be a multiplicative group.

Is 1 $\in \mathbb{G}_T$ ?

I think its true, because if $a \in \mathbb{G}_T$ then $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{G}_T$, So $aa^{-1} =1  \in \mathbb{G}_T$.

Is the above argument true?

Comment: what is $\mathbb G_T$?

Comment: Its just a multiplicative group.

Comment: What is $T$? A ring?

Comment: Part of the definition of a group (any group) is that it contains an identity element.

Comment: @lulu I think $\mathbb G_T$ is the multiplicative group taken out of another structure, sort of like how you can take the multiplicative group of a ring, by taking all the elements with inverses and leaving the product operation.

Comment: @dREaM...maybe you are right.  The notation sure suggests something like that.

Comment: For reference, this horrible notation $\mathbb{G}_T$ is something many cryptographers have adopted in the context of pairing-based cryptography. In typical scenarios, it is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of a finite field.

Answer (score 4):

The axioms for a group $G$ are

1. Associativity
2. The existence of an element $e$ such that $ge = eg = g$ for all $g\in G$.
3. For all $g\in G$ there is a $g^{-1}\in G$ such that $gg^{-1} = g^{-1}g = e$.

So the existence of a multiplicative identity is required by the axioms and isn't something that you have to prove.

Answer (score 3):

It is always true that a group contains a neutral element. However, it is not necessarily "the" $1$ that is this element. Instead it is *customary* to denote the nuetral element in virtually any (multiplicatively written) group by the symbol $1$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition every group $G$ contains an identity/neutral element, that is there is an element $h \in G $ such that $hg=gh = g$ for every $g \in G$.
It can be shown that this element is always unique.

It is not uncommon to use the notation $1_G$ or just $1$ for this element when one uses multiplicative notation.

However, this element, denoted $1$, is not necessarily related to the number $1$ in any way whatsoever.

On your argument: you use at least that the group is non-empty. Indeed, if we were not  requiring the existence of a neutral element as an axiom the empty set would be a group. Moreover, note that $aa^{-1}$ is the neutral element. To define what an inverse is you need a neutral element to begin with.

**Let me add** (based on a comment) that if your group is the subgroup of the multiplicative group of a finite field $F$ then, yes, this subgroup will always contain $1 \in F$, the multiplicative identity of $F$.